# Can I access the "Application Data" folder if my phone is not Jailbroken?

Tags: rooting, sms

I've seen that you can recover your deleted SMS from your phone with [this tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1448197).

However my phone is not Jailbreaken, so I can't use the app, but I was wondering if it's still possible to browse the phone's "Application Data\Outlook" folder from a computer.

I can't check because I have a Mac and I don't know any option to explore WP on a Mac. If you tell me it's possible, I will install Windows (or if there's an option to browse the "Application Data\Outlook" folder from a Mac it's even better !)

Thanks

Jojo

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible access this kind of folder even in Windows if you do not have root access.

Applications that has not root access cannot open files other than the ones in the Hubs.